How to release memory for Java 11 in Docker?
We have a few docker containers that appear to keep building up memory and never releasing it back. When we run the jar files outside of docker, it works just fine. It'll build up and then eventually release the memory. But, once it is inside of docker, it no longer will give up the memory.
How can I get Java to release the memory back to Docker in order to release it back to the OS?
It releases the memory when ran outside of Docker, but doesn't appear to release it inside of Docker.
Running JAR locally
Java Command
java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar

Process Responses ps x -o pid,rss,vsz,command | grep test.jar
Start
34728 155100 47058244 /usr/bin/java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
Large Process
34728 3124876 47273804 /usr/bin/java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
After 5 minutes
34728 110708 47274108 /usr/bin/java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
Running JAR inside Docker
Java Command
java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar

Process Responses in Docker ps x -o pid,rss,vsz,command | grep test.jar
Start
1 212280 14596716 java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
Large Process
1 3570036 16764168 java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
After 5 minutes
1 3571312 16778368 java -Xss15M -XX:MaxHeapSize=10240M -jar test.jar
Attempts

Done lots of Googling, but everything states that this is no longer an issue since Java 9
Set MaxHeapFreeRatio, MaxRAMPercentage, and even MaxRAMFraction to no luck


Are JVMs the same (inside and outside?) ? There are may be different default GCs.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, they are the same. They both use the openjdk-11 version of Java.
